# conda 4.7.12: conda update -n base conda fails

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I am working with conda version 4.7.12. Running the command `conda update -n base conda` failed. I am getting the same result when trying to update other environments as well, but the problem seemed to start when this command failed the first time. The output is:

```
$ conda update -n base conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1208): KeyError(u'pkgs_dirs',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1206, in print_unexpected_error_report
    message_builder.append(get_main_info_str(error_report['conda_info']))
  File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 236, in get_main_info_str
    info_dict['_' + key] = ('\n' + 26 * ' ').join(info_dict[key])
KeyError: u'pkgs_dirs'

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1074, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 265, in install
        should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 415, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1004, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs, self._repodata_fn)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 250, in get_reduced_index
        _supplement_index_with_system(reduced_index)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 155, in _supplement_index_with_system
        cuda_version = context.cuda_version
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
        cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/common/decorators.py", line 20, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 770, in cuda_version
        return cuda_detect()
      File "/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/common/cuda.py", line 19, in cuda_detect
        system = platform.system()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'system'

`$ /home/XXXXXX/miniconda/bin/conda update -n base conda`

  environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError(u'pkgs_dirs',)

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

Comment: It might help to include the output of `conda info` in the question. Also, did it fail while installing `conda=4.7.12` previously? That is already the latest version so not sure why it would bother trying to update when it looks like you already have it.

Comment: Conda had told me that I needed to update conda. That seemed to work, but it downgraded a number of base environment packages. This behavior started after that. I get the same failure when I try to run `conda info`, so there is no info to share with you.

Comment: This appears to be a situation where updating conda introduced an error. I had the same thing happen to me on a Red Hat 7.7 system and a MacOS 10.14.6 system.

Comment: Just a hunch: Maybe `conda info` will run if you provide an explicit `pkgs_dirs`, so something like `CONDA_PKGS_DIR=/home/XXXXXX/miniconda/pkgs conda info`. Though, admittedly, the error seems to be happening upstream with Python failing to find a core library. Another hunch: is there a package in `site-packages` called `platform`? There shouldn't be. Finally, could you add the output of `./miniconda/bin/python -c 'import platform; print(platform.__spec__)'` to your question? Thanks.